# ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import. how to fix it ? python 3.8.5

Tags: python, numpy, conda

I use python 3.8.5
When i running a code i get this error: ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

This is the version list i have (from conda):

```
Package                       Version
----------------------------- ---------
Keras-Applications            1.0.8
Keras-Preprocessing           1.1.2
matplotlib                    3.7.0
matplotlib-inline             0.1.6
networkx                      3.0
numpy                         1.18.5
opencv-python                 4.5.5
pandas                        1.5.3
parso                         0.8.3
patsy                         0.5.3
pickleshare                   0.7.5
Pillow                        9.1.0
pip                           23.0.1
prompt-toolkit                3.0.36
pywin32                       304
PyYAML                        6.0
tensorboard                   2.10.0
tensorboard-data-server       0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit        1.8.1
tensorflow                    2.3.0
tensorflow-estimator          2.3.0
torch                         1.10.1
torchvision                   0.11.2
tornado                       6.2
tqdm                          4.64.1
visualization                 1.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may resolve this error by updating numpy:

```
pip install -U numpy
```

If above query does not work then you can uninstall and reinstall numpy:

```
pip uninstall numpy
```

then:

```
pip install numpy
```